# Sort order for jquery datatable

Tags: jquery

I have created a jquery datatable. I want to apply a secondary sort in such a way that, if we click on a particular column it will sort that column(ascending/descending) and also preserve the first column sorted with respect to the column being clicked.

How can this be done??

Comment: Show us your data structure and code.

Answer (score 2):

By datatable do you mean DataTables? If so, click on one to sort then hold down shift and click on another to sort it while preserving the original sort.

http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/dom_sort.html

Comment: Well that s correct, but i want a scenario in which if I click on lets say 4th column, then it should automatically sort 4th column and preserver the 1st column sorted with respect to 4th column

Comment: I do not want to use shift and click key.

Comment: It is possible just not supported out of the box. See this thread: http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/3641/multi-column-sorting-without-shift-click/p1